# Does using a prototype + definition instead of just a definition speed up the program?

Tags: c, function, prototype

Im very new to C programing, but have limited experience with Python, Java, and Perl. I was just wondering what the advantage is of having the prototype of a function above main() and the definition of that function below main() rather than just having the definition of said function above main(). From what I have read, the definition can act as a prototype as well.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The use of a prototype above `main()` (within a single module) is mostly a matter of personal preference. Some people like to see `main()` at the bottom of the file; other people like to see it at the top. I had a professor in university who complained that I wrote my programs "upside-down" because I put `main()` at the bottom (and avoided having to write and maintain prototypes for everything).

There is one situation where a prototype may be required:

```
void b(); // prototype required here

void a()
{
    b();
}

void b()
{
    a();
}
```

In this *mutually recursive* situation, you need at least one of the prototypes to appear prior to the definition of the other function.

Comment: Keep in mind that code is to illustrate a concept (and it does it well), but infinitely recursive code should be avoided in real life :-)

Comment: In that example it's infinite, but mutual recursive calling does not necessarily imply infinite recursion.

Comment: Thats great! I was just wondering if the program would undergo any speed decreases/increases depending on the method used, but I see this is not the case. Thanks

Comment: That's right, I forgot to mention that the use of prototypes is not directly related to performance.

Comment: I assumed thats what you meant after not even mentioning it :D . Again, thanks

Answer (score 3):

- When someone else wants to use your library, you can give them the header (containing the prototypes), without giving them your code.

  Example? Windows SDK.
- If two functions call each other, you will need to have a prototype for at least one of them.

There is no performance impact* on the compiled code.

*Note: Well, there *could* be, I guess. If the compiler decides to put the method somewhere else in the binary, then you could theoretically see locality issues affecting the performance of your application. It's not something to normally worry about, though.

Comment: True, but this doesn't address the usage of a separate declaration inside of a source file. (Presumably it is a private function) -- okay, +1 for addressing the performance impact, but the first bullet still seems isolated :)

Answer (score 2):

There's no advantage in splitting a function into a standalone prototype and a definition. In fact, there's a clear and explicit *disadvantage* to that approach, since it requires extra maintenance efforts to keep the prototype and the definition in perfect sync. For this reason, a reasonable approach would be to provide a separate prototype only when you *have* to. For example, with external functions declared in header files you have no other choice but to keep the prototype and definition separate.

As for functions internal to a single translation unit (the ones that we'd normally declare `static`) there's absolutely no reason to create a standalone prototype, since the definition of the function itself includes a prototype. Just define your functions in the natural order: low level functions first, high level functions last, and that's it. If your program consists of a single translation unit, the `main` function will end up at the very bottom.

The only case you'd have to declare a standalone prototype in this approach would be if some form of recursion was involved.

Answer (score 1):

If you write your code in the correct order, i.e. main last, then there is only one definition in your code for each function. This prevents having to change the code in two, or more, places if changes ever need to be made. That prevents errors and reduces the work to maintain it. The principle is called "[single source of truth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Source_of_Truth)"

Comment: From what I have been reading, everything points toward the correct way being to have the main() near the top, after the prototypes, but before the definitions. But I see that this isnt the most practical way of writing/maintaining large programs.